# Good Java HTML package?

Tags: java, html

I need some utility class to use in order to write some results to a html file. I did this manually and it works but I'm pretty sure there has to be some free existing package out there that is more reliable, easy to use and formats the html in a nice way. Any suggestions?

I don't need a HTML parser, but something to generate good-looking HTML.

Comment: Does it have to generate good looking HTML? Couldn't it generate good-functioning HTML and if you have to, run it through a beautifier? :-)

Comment: I'd prefer doing as little work as possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using [Google Closer templates](http://code.google.com/closure/templates/docs/helloworld_java.html).  Some other (and maybe more commonly used) suggestions are the [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) library.  [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) is another option as well.

Its worth mentioning that all of them provide basic logical constructs (if/else/foreach) within your template files, so its up to you to decide to use them or not.  This is the source of a lot of criticisms for these frameworks because it doesn't encourage the decoupling of controllers and views that MVC pattern calls for.